# Why am i getting 'undefined' from this JSON object?

Tags: javascript, undefined

```js
var action=component.get("c.callCostCatalog");
        
action.setParams({ wrapperStructure:JSON.stringify(component.get("v.listStructurePV")),
              consumoTotal:component.get("v.consumTotal"), 
              Rate:'Vacia',
              orderItemID: component.get("v.recordId"),
              PMPInicial:component.get("v.precioInicial")})

action.setCallback(this,function(response){
//var listWrapper = JSON.parse(response.getReturnValue()); -> log shows [object object]
var listWrapper = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.getReturnValue()));
//listWrapper.usedBand returns undefined
})
```

`callCostCatalog` is an Apex method which returns the string:

```
{"usedBand":0.0,"PMPObjetivo":0.0,"PMPNegotiated":0.028533,"PMPInit":0.028533,"negotiationBands":null,"Negotiation":0.0,"negBandCI":null,"minBandSD":null,"minBandRZ":null,"minBandRT":null,"minBandD":null,"minBand":null,"maxBandSD":null,"maxBandRZ":null,"maxBandRT":null,"maxBandD":null,"maxBand":null,"lNegotiatedPrices":[80.97],"lInitPrices":[0.028533],"lImplicitPrice":[],"lConsums":[]}
```

Comment: Do `JSON.parse(aux)` without the `JSON.stringify` part.

Comment: `aux2` is a string, not an object.

Comment: @Barmar https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(something))` will return a value of the same type as `something`. Since `aux` is a string. so is `aux2`.

Comment: Okay, hopefully this shows why it's better to write a proper answer in the answer section than to drop vague/incomplete clues in the comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `JSON.parse` is right, and your `console.log` is right, and your JSON is valid.

However, you have erroneously called `JSON.stringify`, which is like the reverse of `parse`, taking a JavaScript object and producing a string of JSON. You don't want that; you already have a string of JSON. Simply remove it.

Comment: "taking a JavaScript object and producing a string of JSON" — The input isn't a JavaScript object, it is a JavaScript string.

Comment: @Quentin Is that not an object? It's a thing, an entity, in JavaScript.

Comment: @Quentin that statement wasn't specific to the question and was an example of what `JSON.stringify` does, hence the prefix "which is like the reverse of `parse`"

Comment: `aux` is a string, not an object. It's initialized as a string literal on the previous line.

Comment: @phuzi — As a general statement it is still wrong, since it accepts any of the JSON supported data types as input, not just objects.

Comment: @Quentin Use of a string literal converts it to `String`, which is an object. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#string_literals

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings — JS will, under some circumstances, automatically convert a string primitive into a String object. This isn't one of them. [They are different](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#string_primitives_and_string_objects)

Comment: The value of `aux`, as I said previously is a string primitive (not a String object nor any other kind of object) here. That is the value passed to `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: The problem is that the string really comes from a response in an action callback function, thats its: response.getResultValue() to get the json, but if i do JSON.parse(response.getResultValue()), i get '[object object]'. I needed JSON.stringify(response.getResultValue()) to get the string. What should i do?

Comment: @BlueSac The result of JSON.parse _is_ an object! I think someone somewhere has got a bit confused - given the information in the question, you should remove the `stringify` call. If it needs to be there for some other reason, that's not represented in the question.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I tryed to simply the situation, but looks like was worse. I have updated the info. I hope now it's clearer. I receive undefined in the callback response

Comment: @BlueSac Yeah you're going to have to provide a [mcve]. It's all a bit of a jumble now I'm afraid.

Comment: Okey, i'm *****. I was doing

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> var aux = '{"usedBand":0.0,"PMPObjetivo":0.0,"PMPNegotiated":0.028533,"PMPInit":0.028533,"negotiationBands":null,"Negotiation":0.0,"negBandCI":null,"minBandSD":null,"minBandRZ":null,"minBandRT":null,"minBandD":null,"minBand":null,"maxBandSD":null,"maxBandRZ":null,"maxBandRT":null,"maxBandD":null,"maxBand":null,"lNegotiatedPrices":[80.97],"lInitPrices":[0.028533],"lImplicitPrice":[],"lConsums":[]}';
> ```

It starts out as a string of JSON that represents an object.

---

> ```
> JSON.stringify(aux)
> ```

Then you turn it into a string of JSON (that represents a string of JSON that represents an object).

---

> ```
> JSON.parse(...);
> ```

Then you parse it, which gives you the original string of JSON back.

---

Strings don't have `usedBand` properties.

You need to parse your original JSON **without** converting it **to** nested JSON first.

```js
var aux = '{"usedBand":0.0,"PMPObjetivo":0.0,"PMPNegotiated":0.028533,"PMPInit":0.028533,"negotiationBands":null,"Negotiation":0.0,"negBandCI":null,"minBandSD":null,"minBandRZ":null,"minBandRT":null,"minBandD":null,"minBand":null,"maxBandSD":null,"maxBandRZ":null,"maxBandRT":null,"maxBandD":null,"maxBand":null,"lNegotiatedPrices":[80.97],"lInitPrices":[0.028533],"lImplicitPrice":[],"lConsums":[]}';

var aux2 = JSON.parse(aux);

console.log(aux2.usedBand);
```

Comment: The `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object))` pattern is a cheap way to deep-clone a javascript object, which is why you may have seen it used in the past, but it is important to understand what each step does.

Comment: @mix3d Not *that* cheap (deep-cloning anything is expensive), but rather simple and one-liner...

Comment: And with hopefully obvious caveats of only copying stringable values, ignoring functions, etc.

Comment: The problem is that the string really comes from a response in an action callback function, thats its: response.getResultValue() to get the json, but if i do JSON.parse(response.getResultValue()), i get '[object object]'. I needed JSON.stringify(response.getResultValue()) to get the string. What should i do?

Comment: `JSON.parse` will only output `'[object object]'` if you put `'"[object object]"'` into it in the first place, which seems unlikely. More likely you are just doing something to convert an object to a (non-JSON) string somewhere along the line. Either way, the code you have in the question doesn't reproduce the problem you are actually having, so its very hard to tell what is really going on.

Comment: I have updated the code